# Как получить EventArgs из ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, maui

Пытаюсь реализовать смену темы приложения на темную и светлую. Использую Switch и EventToCommandBehavior из Community Toolkit Maui.
Пример кода, который работает во View.

```
private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    ICollection<ResourceDictionary> mergedDictionaries = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
    if (mergedDictionaries != null)
    {
        mergedDictionaries.Clear();
        switch (e.Value.ToString())
        {
            case "True":
                mergedDictionaries.Add(new BlackStyle());
                break;
            case "False":
                mergedDictionaries.Add(new WhiteStyle());
                break;
                
        }
    }
}
```

Как реализовать тоже самое, только во ViewModel?
Как получить значение ToggledEventArgs e во ViewModel?

Comment: `e.Value.ToString()` xDDD - весь код можно заменить на `mergedDictionaries.Add(e.Value ? new BlackStyle() : new WhiteStyle());`

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос не в этом.

Comment: А вы не должны хотеть это делать в ViewModel, это не его обязанности. MVVM - это про разделение все на слои, малосвязанные друг с другом слои, где каждый слой отвечает за что-то конкретное. Model - данные (база, файл, сайт, и прочее); View - вид (UI) приложения (всякие кнопочки, цвета, картинки, стили, и др.); ViewModel - некий связующий слой, который общается с моделью, подготавливает нужное для привязки View слоя. Вот теперь задайте вопрос - стиль, словари стилей, это к какому слою относится? Единственное, что может быть в VM, так это `public bool IsBlackTheme {get; set;}`, не более.

Comment: Верно, ViewModel вообще ничего нк должна знать о том, какая тема включена. Эта задача на 100% должна решаться внутри View.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Почему-то я считал, что во ViewModel хранится логика приложения. А так как смена словаря ресурса происходит от Switch, которая выполняет команду, значит, что код должен находиться во ViewModel.